# Chat application database

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables
users ( user_id , name )
thread ( thread_id , date_time)
subscribers ( subscriber_id , thread_id)
subscriber id is a foreign key from users table how can i get thread of 2 specefic users , i'm doing something like this but it's giving me blank rows

```
SELECT t.thread_id, s.subscriber_id, u.user_id
FROM subscribers s
LEFT JOIN thread t ON t.thread_id = s.thread_id
LEFT JOIN user u ON s.subscriber_id = u.user_id
WHERE s.subscriber_id = 1 AND s.subscriber_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your query as @Tim Biegeleisen said.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when i wrote my answer there were no other answers, I'm sorry, you want me to remove my answer i guess since you voted it down?

Comment: Edited my answer sir.

Comment: You didn't need to delete it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I will highlight the portion of your query which is causing the empty set result:

```
WHERE s.subscriber_id = 1 AND s.subscriber_id =2
                           ^ really?
```

You are asking MySQL to return records where the `subscriber_id` is both `1` *and* `2`.  This doesn't make any sense.  In the corrected query below I have changed the `WHERE` condition to use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, t.thread_id
FROM users u INNER JOIN susbscribers s ON u.user_id = s.subscriber_id
INNER JOIN thread t ON s.thread_id = t.thread_id
WHERE u.user_id = 1 OR u.user_id = 2
```